# GWT bug!? ClickHandler not firing when CSS "position: absolute" added

Tags: css, gwt, handler, css-position

(GWT 2.4.0)

After adding CSS : "position: absolute" (see code attached), GWT events "ClickHandler" stop working. 
Bug tested on Chrome 16.0.9 and FireFox 8.0, On IE 9 code works fine.
(Full code snipet on github : https://gist.github.com/1533904).
Is this GWT bug or I'm doing something wrong ?

File : client.MySampleApplication.java

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    final Button button = new Button("Click me");
    button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Window.alert("ahtung");
        }
    });
    RootPanel.get("slot1").add(button);

    final Button button2 = new Button("Click me2");
    button2.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Window.alert("ahtung2");
        }
    });
    RootPanel.get("slot2").add(button2);
}
```

File : web.MySampleApplication.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Wrapper HTML for App</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
            src="MySampleApplication/MySampleApplication.nocache.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slot1" style="position: absolute; padding-top: 50px; padding-left: 150px;" ></div>
    <div id="slot2" style="position: absolute; padding-top: 100px; padding-left: 150px;" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your divs are one on top of the other: both are positionned at `0,0`; `slot1` is at least `50px` tall (plus the height of the button you put inside), and `slot2` is positioned on top (because it comes after in the document, and they have the same `z-index`) and at least `100px` tall, therefore covering `slot1`.

You probably want to use `top` rather than `padding-top`, and `left` rather than `padding-left`.

Comment: thanks Tomas!
position: absolute, top and left works for me great !